# Collect CPU, reads and writes when replaying SQL Profiler Trace

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to replay a trace on a test environment with SQL Profiler in order to benchmark a database prior to making some performance tweaks. I intend to replay the same trace at various stages to compare the stats and measure the improvements.

I've been following the post at [keepitsimpleandfast](http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2010/08/use-sql-profiler-replay-traces-to.html) which seems good however I'm not getting the CPU, Reads and Writes data saved when I replay the trace in **Step 6.**.

I had to add the CPU, Reads and writes columns to events when I set up the **TSQL-Replay** template when I took the trace but I don't have any options in Replay Configuration to select events or columns.

Strangely, I also ran a separate trace first and then replay the trace nothing gets traced at all! The events are different though, instead of *RPC: Completed* I get *Replay Result Set Event* and *Replay Result Row Event*, would this make a difference?

Does anyone know how to either amend the columns logged when you replay a trace *OR* how to set up another trace to trace the replay?

Comment: I have tired it,but unfortunately trace replay does not show the CPU, reads and writes. It might be a limitation - that what I am guessing ... may be someone that has played with Trace Replay explain more on this ...